# Stripe.JS - createSource with additional data (owner)

Tags: javascript, stripe-payments

I am developing a shopping cart checkout page with Stripe.js and Stripe Elements, not using the checkout widget from Stripe.

On the checkout page all 4 elements available (cards, postal_code, expirey and Cvc) are used.

To get a unique PCI compliant creditcard checkout, I dont use the JS function "createToken" but instead (for compatibility reasons at the API side) I use "createSource" - which create a unique source instead of a token.

The usage is the same then with a credit card token, but a source object is updatable - so if I don't get it wrong - a source update can have "metadata" as it is updatable (documentation says only updatable objects can have metadata).

My question is: How do I use the Javascript framework to add additional owner data that can be used to extend the fraud-protection.

I want to collect the creditcard owners full-name, his country of residence and email address and add it to the createSource call, but it wont show up on the stripe dashboard at the created source.

**Example source code**

```
stripe
  .createSource(cardNumber,{
    owner: {
      address: { country: country },
      email: email,
      name : name
    }
  })...
```

The stripe documentation is missing a "search function" and google doesn't give me results I can really use.

Maybe some stripe developers/users can help me with this problem.

Thanks for reading! :)

Comment: Did you tried this https://stripe.com/docs/elements/examples#example-3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hi i had the same problem but i am using direct api instead of using `stripe.js` You can create your own form then then post form at `https://api.stripe.com/v1/sources`

Here is example to do this in javascript and html form

```html
<form action="https://api.stripe.com/v1/sources" method="post" id="payment-form">
card number          <input type="text" name="card[number]" value="4242424242424242" ><br/>
card cvc             <input type="text" name="card[cvc]" value="424" ><br/>
card exp_month       <input type="text" name="card[exp_month]" value="12" ><br/>
card exp_year        <input type="text" name="card[exp_year]" value="50" ><br/>
owner name           <input type="text" name="owner[name]" value="test user" ><br/>
owner verified_phone <input type="text" name="owner[verified_phone]" value="yes" ><br/>
owner address        <input type="text" name="owner[address][city]" value="Dubai" ><br/>
owner address        <input type="text" name="owner[address][country]" value="UAE" ><br/>
owner address        <input type="text" name="owner[address][line1]" value="line1" ><br/>
owner address        <input type="text" name="owner[address][line2]" value="line2" ><br/>
owner address        <input type="text" name="owner[address][state]" value="state" ><br/>
owner email          <input type="text" name="owner[email]" value="email@gmail.com" ><br/>
owner phone          <input type="text" name="owner[phone]" value="00971521234567" ><br/>
owner address        <input type="text" name="owner[address][postal_code]" value="2424" ><br/>
<input type="hidden" name="type" value="card" >
<input type="hidden" name="key" value="pk_test_IR0lZ3Ot5IQnsde6xuAmkHvB" >
<input type="submit" value="Save">
  </form>
```

I hope it will help you.